# How to update multiple documents meta data in sharepoint using Sharepoint Rest API

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-api, sharepoint-rest-api

How to update multiple documents meta data in sharepoint using Sharepoint Rest API

Ex: 4 documents exist in sharepoint, i  wanted to update its columns with some values like "Status": "Active". when i did loop though it works for2 records update and 3rd records getting the timeout issues as exceptions in rest API.

Request sample- I'm using HTTPHelper.cs and SPOAuthUtility.cs for integration

```
  HttpWebRequest webRequestChild = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(urlChild);
                webRequestChild.ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose";
                // webRequestChild.Method = "POST";
                //webRequestChild.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
                webRequestChild.Headers.Add("X-RequestDigest", digest);
                webRequestChild.Headers.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
                webRequestChild.Headers.Add("If-Match", "*");
                webRequestChild.UserAgent = "NONISV|contoso|GovernanceCheck/1.0"; //Contoso - Company name 
                webRequestChild.Accept = "application/json; charset=utf-8; odata=verbose";
                webRequestChild.Headers.Add("content-length", contentChild.Length.ToString());
                webRequestChild.Timeout = 1000000;
                webRequestChild.ReadWriteTimeout = 32000;
```

Comment: Could you please provide (for example codepen) your code?

Comment: Added sample code for the reference , I want to loop each files to update metadata column in the above request  and send it